# Run Web Pages (with Extjs) on Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, extjs, eclipse-plugin, ide

I use Eclipse as an IDE for php/javascript/Extjs 4 its just when I want to run the web page, using internal web browser. php and html web pages are running fine. but html page that contains Extjs scripts showing white page, with no errors. Even though I Installed the Eclipse plugin (Spket)

The scripts are working fine on the web server/web browser (localhost) , but not inside the eclipse internal web browser.

Answer (score 0):

I'm also facing same problem, it is because your extjs files and html files work in localhost root directory, so when you run them using localhost address from browser, they will run but in eclipse, the html page is not run like this. so it'll not be able to run..!