# TFS with eclipse as source control - How to download shared project?

Tags: eclipse, version-control, tfs, ide

I'm trying to use TFS with eclipse as source control. I'm developing a web application. So I'm wondering how my team can download the shared project in their web server folder (Apache httpd - htdocs folder) so that they can test and run web pages in browser. Internal browser not working with js/extjs files (details here: [Run Web Pages (with Extjs) on Eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15346809/run-web-pages-with-extjs-on-eclipse) )

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you want to run a continuous integration build to deploy this out to the central location for testing.

The idea is that when you check in your work, TFS will trigger a build.  That build should be configured to deploy the website to the appropriate testing server.

From there, your team can access whatever they need.